# Formal statement that an analytic function injective on the boundary is injective on the closure

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been told that such a result guaranteeing injectivity on the closure of the domain exists, however I have not been able to find a formal statement of this result. If someone could provide I would be very grateful.

Comment: At least such a statement would need to mean boundary and closure in $\Bbb C\cup\{\infty\}$, not $\Bbb C$. Otherwise, constant functions on $\Bbb C^\times$ are counterexamples

Comment: There is still a problem with both $z$ and $z^2$ agree on $\{0,\infty\}=\partial\mathbb{C}^\times$, $z\mapsto z$ is obviously injective on $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ but $z\mapsto z^2$ is not on $\mathbb{C}^\times$.

Comment: I think we need much stronger hypotheses such as bounded simply-connected Lipschitz domain.  Multiply-connected domain will clearly give many troubles like $z\mapsto z^2$ on $\mathbb{C}-\text{small disc around }z_0\neq 0$, and @HagenvonEitzen example with non-Lipschitz boundary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct version of this claim, sometimes known as Darboux's theorem (sometimes also Picard-Darboux theorem), requires the boundary to be a jordan curve, that is:

> Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on a Jordan region such that it has
> a continuous extension to the boundary. If $f$ is injective on the
> boundary, it is injective on the region.

The proof, roughly sketched, is like this:

Let $\gamma$ be the jordan curve and $\Omega$ be the region bounded by the curve. Since $f$ is continuous and injective, $f(\gamma)$ is a jordan curve. First note that $f(\Omega)$ must be bounded by $f(\gamma)$, since if it is not there must be a $w_0:f(z)-w_0$ has at least a solution in $\Omega$ and not on $\gamma$. This is impossible by the argument principle. Similarly, $f(\Omega)\cap f(\gamma)=\emptyset$ for otherwise the open map theorem implies that $f(\Omega)$ is not bounded by $f(\gamma)$. Now let $w$ be such that $f(z)=w$ has at least one solution on $\Omega$. It is easy to see, by the argument principle and the fact that a positively oriented jordan curve has winding numer $1$, that it must have only one solution. Thus $f$ is one-one on $\Omega\cup \gamma$.

It is easy to see that the following weaker statement has a quite straightforward proof:

> Let $\gamma$ be a closed jordan curve bounding a region $\Omega$, and
> let $f$ be holomorphic on a neighbourhood of $\overline\Omega$. If it
> is injective on $\gamma$, its injective on $\gamma\cup \Omega$.

As the example by @HagenVonEitzen shows, the hypotesis that $\partial \Omega$ is a jordan curve cannot be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

The claims seems to be wrong (or at least needs a more careful formulation than what I read from the OP).

Start with the unit disk $\Bbb D$ and apply the map $f\colon z\mapsto (z+\sqrt 2)^4$, which turns $\Bbb D$ into a domain $\Omega$ that is disk-ish, but its boundary is eight-ish, i.e., the two points $-\frac{\sqrt 2}2\pm \frac{i\sqrt 2}2$ of $\partial \Bbb D$ both end up as $-1\in\partial \Omega$.

Now on $\overline{\Bbb D}$, consider $g\colon z\mapsto (z+\frac{\sqrt2}2)^2$. This is not injective in $\Bbb D$, but it is injective in $\partial \Bbb D$ with the sole exception that $g(-\frac{\sqrt 2}2+ \frac{i\sqrt 2}2)=g(-\frac{\sqrt 2}2- \frac{i\sqrt 2}2)$ (the only points where $S^1+\frac{\sqrt 2}2$ intersects $-(S^1+\frac{\sqrt 2}2)=S^1-\frac{\sqrt 2}2$). Now on $\overline\Omega$, the map $g\circ f^{-1}$ is well-defined, is continuous, is analytic in $\Omega$, is injective on $\partial \Omega$, but is not injective in $\Omega$.